# identify what webpage URL is opened in php

Tags: php

i have a php page that logs in an account as if the real person is doing it. i would like to put in a php script that checks the webpage URL currently opened. the page works this way:

> 1. i run localhost/loginmirror/index.php from my browser.
> 2. new browser window is automatically opened. page loaded is the URL of the page i placed on my code (ex: https://twitter.com/).
> 3. i use php scripts to put in the username and password and click the Login button. everything necessary for input and clicking is done by
>      my php code. no human needed. after clicked, i am redirected to the
>      next page and so on and so on.

i would like to get the URL of the particular page now opened. i have tried using

> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

but it retrieves this: `loginmirror/index.php` instead of returning which page in google mail is now opened.

how do i get the URL that i want to retrieve? thanks

Comment: You cannot do this in PHP.  You are trying to use server-side language to control front-end process unrelated to this web app - this is not possible, not least because of security issues.

Comment: Can you please explain what did you meant by `which page in google mail is now opened.`??